Data display on second click
import React from "react";
import Button from "./Button";
import Section from "./Section";
import { Dragendrop } from "./Dragendrop";

export const RightBox = () => {
  const [fileData, setFileData] = React.useState();
  const [data, setData] = React.useState(null);
  const [recieverAddress, setReceiverAddress] = React.useState("");

  const handleFileData = (data) => {
    setFileData(data);
  };

  const upload = () => {
    if (fileData.length > 0) {
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function (fileEvent) {
        const f = fileEvent.target.result;
        setData(f);
        console.log(data);
      };
      reader.readAsDataURL(fileData[0]);
    }
  };
  
  //
  const checkUser = () => {
  
  };

  return (
    <div className="w-1/2 h-[45rem] mb-5 bg-stone-900 p-2 rounded-md">
      <div className="flex gap-2">
        <input
          type="text"
          onChange={(e) => {
            setReceiverAddress(e.target.value);
          }}
          className="w-full p-3 font-code rounded-md"
          placeholder="Reciever Id"
        />
        <Button onClick={checkUser}>Check</Button>
      </div>
      <Section
        className="w-full h-[580px] -mx-2 my-3"
        crosses
        customPaddings
        id="data"
      >
        <div className="container">
          <Dragendrop onFileData={handleFileData} />
        </div>
      </Section>
      <div className="w-full">
        <Button onClick={upload} className="w-full content-end flex">
          Send
        </Button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};


On clicking send button, upload function runs,
according to upload function it should read file data and store to setData() state and
console.log(data),
but it don't print files data on first click,
on second click it prints the data.
I got consfuse, why console.log(data) prints filedata on second click,not on first click.
so, the file data should print on the first click only.

by updating the state data with the setter setData(f), you are actually only telling React to update the state, but the state is not actually updated yet until the next render. When console.log(data) runs the first time, the state does not yet hold the new value. By the second time you run console.log(data), that is, the second time you press the button, the state has been updated with the new value.
React docs explaining why your situation happens.
